# Office.js Add-in not working with dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, excel, knockout.js, office-js

I am trying to bind data to an excel spreadsheet using Office.js, however the columns are a span of date ranges that can vary per project. Below is the code I've been using to handle static columnns, and it works great for that. However, as the column range changes, I get this error: The supplied data object does not match the size of the current selection. The property that contains the dynamic columns is self.VisibleBudgetDownloadColumns(). I've tried several different approaches but there are limited examples on how to handle this. I'm essentially looking for a way to update the columns as well as the data. Thanks in advance!

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var activeWorksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        var currentRows = GetRows(self.BudgetDownload(), self.BudgetDownload().length, self.VisibleBudgetDownloadColumns(), self.VisibleBudgetDownloadColumns().length);

        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(bindingID,
                    function (asyncResult) {
                        // if binding exists, delete and update rows
                        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                            asyncResult.value.deleteAllDataValuesAsync();
                            asyncResult.value.addRowsAsync(currentRows,
                                function (asyncResult) {
                                    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                                        self.showErrorMessageBar(asyncResult.error.message);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        else { // create new binding
                            var td = new Office.TableData();
                            td.rows = currentRows;
                            td.headers = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.VisibleBudgetDownloadColumns(),
                                function (item) {
                                    return item.DisplayName;
                                });

                            Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(td,
                                function (result) {
                                    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                                        self.showErrorMessageBar(result.error.message);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync(Office.BindingType.Table, { id: bindingID },
                                            function (asyncResult) {
                                                if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                                                    self.showErrorMessageBar(asyncResult.error.message);
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    asyncResult.value.setDataAsync(td, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table },
                                                        function (result) {
                                                            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                                                                self.showErrorMessageBar(result.error.message);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    );
                                                }
                                            }
                                        );
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        overlay.hide();
        self.showErrorMessageBar(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things while you're waiting for a better answer:

1. Your outer structure is an `Excel.run` from the host-specific Excel.js APIs, but most of the logic inside it is from the Shared (also called Common) APIs. When you need to use both sets of APIs, the calls to the Shared APIs should be wrapped in a Promise-returning function. For an example, see the `getDocumentFilePath` function in this file: [Home.js in Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-MarkdownConversion/blob/master/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-MDConversionWeb/Home.js) and scroll up in the same file to see how it is called.
2. That said, you should try to do as much work as you can using the host-specific APIs. A colleague has suggested that the Range.getCell() and Range.getResizedRange() methods might suit your scenario. Especially, if you chain them: `getCell(0,0).getResizedRange(…)`.
3. I'm puzzled by the 4 `ctx.sync` calls in a row at the end.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I've made a few edits to the code above and wrapped the the shared API in a promise. Also removed the extra ctx.sync calls from the bottom for now.